# FBSDKLikeControl with iOS10 does not works

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

I want to use a FBSDKLikeControl button in my app. Thats works on iOS11 but with iOS10 Safari disappear 1 sec after... and back in my app.

Do you know Why?

Thanks

Comment: With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, the Like Button for iOS is deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/archive/docs/sharing/ios/like-button/

Answer (score 0):

I found this, hope it can help.

> With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, the Like Button
>   for iOS is deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018.

source : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/like-button/

Comment: There does not seem to be any replacement for the API - not in the core-code, not in the web-docs. That's more than sad to see, because devs need to go back to display ugly web-frames like done 5 years ago.